# How to read Origin HTTP Header and send response 404 in apache httpd

Tags: apache-http-server, http, httpd, cors

I have a penetration test finding that needs to block request from client if its 'Origin' Header didn't meet the criteria, for example it must be '192.168.2.123:8888'.

If the Header was 'Host', I have successfully handle it by configure these in `<VirtualHost>`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,20}.){0,3}192.168.2.123:8888$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.2.123:8888/app/ui [R=404,L]
```

But for 'Origin' Header, I can't get HTTP_ORIGIN (I'm not sure whether that predefined variable exist).
I have configured these but not working:

```
<If "req('Origin') != '192.168.2.123:8888'">
    ErrorDocument 404 default
</If>
```

How can I find the configuration to read 'Origin' and send response 404 for it?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} ^(?!\s*$).+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} !^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,20}.){0,3}192.168.2.123:8888$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

It will send response '403 Forbidden'